# Passing composite data in rxjs observable chains

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a block of code where I'm calling observables in a chain like so:

```
getData().flatMap(results => {
   return callNextDataMethod(results);
}
.flatMap(results2 => {
   // next operation and so forth
})
```

Now, I understand that flatMap will allow me to pass the results of the previous observable to the next one.  However what I need is to both do that as well as pass the results on the first.  Let's assume that I do some cleanup, validation, etc on the data that comes back in getData and I want that passed to all flatMap calls down the chain.  Is there an operator in rxjs that will do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `map` operator to combine the argument received by the `flatMap` projection function with the observable's result:

```js
getData()
  .flatMap(data =>
    getMoreData(data).map(moreData => ({ data, moreData }))
  )
  .flatMap(({ data, moreData }) =>
    getEvenMoreData(moreData).map(evenMoreData => ({ data, moreData, evenMoreData }))
  )
  .flatMap(({ data, moreData, evenMoreData }) =>
    ...
```

Comment: Thx.  Still a little stuck.  Tried your example but the code fails unfortunately:

Comment: this.getStuffOne()
     .flatMap(data => {
       debugger;
       this.getStuffTwo().map(moreData => {data, moreData});
     })
     .flatMap((data, moreData) => {
       debugger;
       this.getStuffThree().map(evenMoreData => {data, moreData, evenMoreData});
     })

Comment: I've updated the answer. It had some syntax errors - the `{}` needed to be wrapped in `()`, etc.

Comment: The chain from the first internal map to data, moreData appears to be null.  I get a can't subscribe error before the second flatMap is hit

Comment: The code in your comment does not appear to be returning anything from within the arrow functions - there is no `return` for the observable effected by the `getStuffTwo`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Been banging my head on this!