# multiple httpclient request that depends on data from another httpclient request using observables

Tags: nested, observable, angular-httpclient

I'm re-writing an application in angular 5 that fetch data from a server and download some pdf files. The server is a soap interface with 3 api:

1 - get the list of campaigns

2 - get files array by campaign id

3 - get a file by file id

I've already done this with pure XMLHTTPRequest and some recursive functions that fills a "campaigns" object, extract the cover and saves all the files one after the other.

What i want to get now is to avoid the callback hell and use httpclient and the observables available in angular to obtain the same result, but after two days of study of the rxjs library i still haven't understood how to do it.

I already obtain successfully data with httpclient and i've done lot of try with observable opertors.
The schematic flow of events is:

get campaigns xml =>

transform xml data to an array of campaigns (done with map operator) =>

for each campaign get the filesInfo =>

transform xml data to an array of filesInfo =>

for each file of each campaign get that file =>

extract the cover of the file and save the file.

i'm stuck here:

```
getCampaigns():Observable<Campaign[]>{
    return this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData('campaignsList').pipe(
      map(rawCampaigns => {return this.createCampaignArray(rawCampaigns)})
    )
  }
```

```
this.getCampaigns().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result) //correctly shows an array of campaigns (without the files of course)
})
```

what now? should I use "from" operator to create new observable from the array? Or a foreach on the array and start a new http client request for each campaign? At the end i need an array of campaigns like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'campaign name',
    id: 1234,
    files:[
      {
        name:'file name',
        id: 4321,
        cover: 'base64string'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i need that the files is downloaded one after another and not in parallel

edit:
thanks also to dmcgrandle answer i figured out sone things and after several attempt i came to this:

```
updateCampaigns():Observable<Campaign[]>{
    let updatedCampaigns:Campaign[];
    return this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData( 'campaignList' ).pipe(
      map( rawCampaigns => {
        updatedCampaigns = this.createCampaignsArray( rawCampaigns );
        return updatedCampaigns;
      } ),
      switchMap( _campaigns => from( _campaigns ).pipe(
        concatMap( _campaign => this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData( 'campaignDocuments', _campaign.id ) )
      ) ),
      map((rawDocuments,i)=>{
        updatedCampaigns[ i ].documents = this.createDocumentsArray( rawDocuments );
        return;
      } ),
      reduce( () => {
        let { campaigns, documentsToDowloadIdList } = this.mergeWithStoredData( updatedCampaigns );
        updatedCampaigns = campaigns;
        return documentsToDowloadIdList;
      } ),
      switchMap( list => from( list ).pipe(
        concatMap( documentId => this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData( 'document', documentId ).pipe(
          map( b64file => { return { documentId:documentId, b64file:b64file } } )
        ) )
      ) ),
      concatMap( file => this.saveFile( file.b64file, file.fileId ) ),
      tap( fileInfo => {
        updatedCampaigns.forEach( campaign => { campaign.documents.forEach( document => {
          if( fileInfo.fileId == document.id ) {
            document.cover = fileInfo.b64cover;
            document.numPages = fileInfo.numPages;
          }
        } ) } )
      } ),
      reduce( () => {
        this.storageservice.set( 'campaigns' , updatedCampaigns );
        return updatedCampaigns;
      } )
    )
  }
```

Note that i've modified the saveFile function, now it return an observable.
Now, this works... I'm wondering if there's a simpler way and if I'm missing something. 
I am also trying to handle errors with catchError operator, but if i use throw, the type of the observable becomes void and I have to put the type "any" instead "Campaign[]" to make it work.
Last thing, i would prefer this observable to return the campaigns object every time it is updated with a new document, so as to display the covers when the file is downloaded and not all together at the end... it's possible to do that?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please consider marking it as correct and/or upvoting it.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do this all in a single function.  Once you have the array of campaigns, emit each item one at a time and do the transformations on each item, one emission at a time.  Then finally put the results all into an array and return that from the function.

During development I would also insert tap()s at each stage to see what is going on after each transformation to make sure it's functioning as expected.

Using pseudo-code, it would look something like this:

```
getCovers(): Observable<Cover[]> {
  return this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData('campaignsList').pipe(
    map(rawCampaigns => this.createCampaignArray(rawCampaigns)),
    concatAll(), // emit the array one item at a time
    concatMap(campaign => this.getFileInfo(campaign)), // get FileInfo for each campaign
    concatMap(fileInfo => this.getTheFile(fileInfo)), // get the File for each fileInfo
    concatMap(file => this.saveTheFileAndGetCover(file)), // save the file, return the cover
    toArray() // put the results into an array for returning.
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to cram an iterative approach to solving this problem into a functional paradigm, which will be very convoluted and hard.  I don't know enough about your data to re-write this all for you, but try and think in terms of streams of data and transforming that stream.  For example, you have a method-scoped array `updatedCampaigns` you are modifying many times in the chain.  Don't do that - instead have the chain itself carry the items from the campaigns array, modifying them as it goes along.  This may allow you to emit a new campaign for each document ...

Comment: Another hint - within your `catchError()`, return the observable function `throwError()` to reintroduce an error back into the Observable stream, don't use `throw`.  Docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError)

Comment: I tried but i found problems with the types of the objects that i carry.... for example, i can not assign an observable to the campaign.document property. if I only use the "any" type then it's easier, but so I lose the usefulness of typescript and it doesn't seem like a best practice. Take for example the first switchmap, how would you do to carry the original array into the next two operators?

Comment: to carry the original array, just have the function `this.getRawDataProvider.getRawData()` piped into the map() operator which maps the return into a new array containing both pieces of data you want - the return from the function and the original array.  See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598605/passing-composite-data-in-rxjs-observable-chains) where Cartant uses an object instead of an array, but the same idea applies.