# Mapping data to Observable Array 1 based on field value from Observable Array 2

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to map data to arr1 based on a field value from arr2 and am running into issues with what order the data is requested.
I am using the following languages listed below in my package.json file.

To (hopefully) better explain what I am trying to do: There are two arrays of arrays (e.g. arr1 = { Locations[]} and arr2 = {Activated Locations[]) where the base array is the Firestore collection and nested documents are the inner array - that applies to both arr1 and arr2. So the inner arrays contain a field "activatedId" which is what I am trying to use as the common element that determines whether the inner array of arr1 contains a field that is mapped as "activated": true (or false).
Also, I am sure many will scoff at my code as I am just getting my feet wet with most of the languages :) so please be nice! Thanks for any help offered and If you have suggestions on how to accomplish this more efficiently I'd love to hear your input.

Thanks from the Noob!

```
    export class LocationListingModel{
      id: string;
      title: string;
      activateId?: string;
      activated: boolean;
    }
```

```
    export class ActiveLocationsModel {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      activateId?: string;
    }
```

```
private  activatedCheck(locationId: string, activatedId: string): boolean {
const locRef = this.afs.doc('locations/' + locationId);
const check = this.afs.collection<LocationDealListingModel>('activatedLocations/', ref => ref
.where('locRef', '==', locRef.ref)
.where('redeemId', '==', activatedId)).snapshotChanges();
if (check.subscribe(res => res.length > 0 )){
  return true;

} else {
  return false;
};
}



 public getsActivatedLocationDataSource(locationId: string, userId: string): Observable<Array<LocationListingModel>> {
let activated: boolean;
const locRef = this.afs.doc('locations/' + locationId);


return this.afs.collection<AvailableDealModel>('locations/', ref => ref.where('locRef', '==', locRef.ref))
  .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
  .pipe(map(actions => actions
    .map(data => {
      const locRef = this.afs.doc('userProfile/' + userId);
      const checkExists = this.afs.collection<LocationDealListingModel>('activeLocations/', ref => ref
        .where('locRef', '==', locRef.ref)
        .where('activeId', '==', data.activeId)).snapshotChanges();
      if (checkExists && (checkExists.subscribe(res => res.length > 0))) {
        activated = true;
      } else if (checkExists && (checkExists.subscribe(res => res.length === 0))) {
        activated = false;
      } else {
        console.log('error completing check. ')
      }

      const id = data.id;
      return { id, active: activated, ...data } as LocationListingModel;

    })
  ));
```

}

### Or Using The First function - activatedCheck()

```
 public getsActivatedLocationDataSource(locationId: string, userId: string): Observable<Array<LocationListingModel>> {
let activated: boolean;
const locRef = this.afs.doc('locations/' + locationId);


return this.afs.collection<AvailableDealModel>('locations/', ref => ref.where('locRef', '==', locRef.ref))
  .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .pipe(map(actions => actions
    .map(data => {
      const checkExists = this.activatedCheck(locationId, activatedId);
      if (checkExists === true) {
        activated = true;
      } else if (checkExists === false) {
        activated = false;
      } else {
        console.log('error completing check. ')
      }
      const id = data.id;
      return { id, active: activated, ...data } as LocationListingModel;
    })
  ));
```

### package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/pwa": "~0.802.1",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^1.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@logisticinfotech/ionic4-datepicker": "^1.4.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "angular-pipes": "^9.0.2",
    "angular-star-rating": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "angularjs-datepicker": "^2.1.23",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "dayjs": "1.8.0",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "geofirex": "0.0.6",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-paypal": "^5.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.3",
    "rxfire": "^3.6.8",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "videogular2": "^7.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.802.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.1",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-angular": "^8.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.7",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.36.2",
    "@types/node": "12.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. There are too many moving parts in your code, many of which simply won't work, and your end goal isn't exactly clear. What do you mean by "common field" between two arrays? As in `arr1[0]` vs `arr2[0]`? Are these two arrays being emitted by Observables?

Comment: Partly. There are two arrays of arrays (e.g. arr1 = { Locations[]} and arr2 = {Activated Locations[]) where the base array is the Firestore collection and nested documents are the inner array - that applies to both arr1 and arr2. So the inner arrays contain a field "activatedId" which is what I am trying to use as the common element that determines whether the inner array of arr1 contains a field that is mapped as "activated": true (or false). Hope that clears it up. It's been a headache for me and I'm not very good with explaining things to real people lol.

Comment: So, if I've got this right, for every element in the `LocationListingModel[]` array, you need to check if there is any element in the `ActiveLocationsModel[]` array whose `activatedId` value matches, and if so, set that `LocationListingModel`'s `activated` value to `true`?

Comment: I'm with Will - It is difficult to determine what you are trying to accomplish.  However, If you are looking to have both arrays available to each of the operators within your Observable chain, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598605/passing-composite-data-in-rxjs-observable-chains) might help.

Comment: @WillAlexander Exactly.

Comment: OK so in that case I'd strongly advise modifying your architecture a bit, perhaps by indexing things on the backend, because otherwise that's going to be an extremely expensive operation (searching an array multiple times). I'm going to put together an answer for what I think you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a big ol' lump of code which I think is close to what you want:

```js
/*
* Dummy data to check everything with
*/
const locations = [
  { activatedId: '1234', activated: false },
  { activatedId: '2345', activated: false },
  { activatedId: '3456', activated: false },
  { activatedId: '4567', activated: false },
  { activatedId: '5678', activated: false },
  { activatedId: '6789', activated: false },
];
const activatedLocations = [
  { activatedId: '1234' },
  { activatedId: '3456' },
  { activatedId: '6789' }
];

/*
* Next we map the activatedLocations Array to an Object
* whose keys are the activatedIds and whose values are true
*/
const indexedActivatedLocations$ = of(activatedLocations).pipe(
  map(locs => {
    const index = {};
    for (let loc of locs) {
      index[loc.activatedId] = true;
    }
    return index;
    // index: { '1234': true, '3456': true, '6789' true }
  })
);

/*
* Finally, we use forkJoin to subscribe to both Observables and
* emit their results as an Array.
* Comparing each location.activatedId to the new Object's keys
* is much faster than searching through an Array again and again
* We change location.activated where necessary and then
* emit the updated Array.
*/
const updatedLocations$ = forkJoin({
  locations: of(locations),
  activated: indexedActivatedLocations$
}).pipe(
  map(data => {
    for (let loc of data.locations) {
      if (data.activated[loc.activatedId]) {
        loc.activated = true;
      }
    }
    return data.locations;
  })
);
```

Comment: It looks very close! I see the results that I am hoping for on the dummy data but once I add in the afs collection The for(let loc of locs) throws the error "Type 'Observable<ActiveLocationsModel[]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator", on both of the for(let of)

Comment: That makes sense if you think about it. I created one Observable which emits an Array, and all you need to do is replace it with your Observable which emits an Array.

Comment: You are a saint sir.I am in your debt.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer to help anyone else with the same problem :)